# Database design - groups chat - seen messages

Tags: database-design

I have an application in which users form groups and chat together. One of the features is the well known "this message was seen at {some date here} by user {some user}". My concern is whether I've designed this correctly as with my current implementation database grows really fast in size.

My approach is really simple. Once a user sends a message to a chat group, assuming there are `N` memebers in that group, `N - 1` rows are created in `chatMessagesSeen` table.

Columns of that table are `id`, `messageId`, `userId`, `groupId`, `date` and `seen`. Last column is a flag used to store whether the message was seen. So that's 4*4+8+1 = 25 bytes per entry. Pretty large chat groups are common, so 100 members in one room is nothing exceptional.

I'd very much appreciate if anyone could share experience with a similiar problem, what should I take into consideration and whether there are any better ways to do this (sure they are, right). I wonder how giant social sites with this feature handle the problem.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative would be to not add those rows right when the message is created, but add a row whenever a user actually reads the message. Then you can omit the `seen` flag – the existence of the row is enough to know that the user saw the message.

That has two advantages:

- fewer table rows
- no extra work when a user joins a group

  With your design, adding a user to a group requires adding a row for every message written by someone in the group.